# Deducing bounds on operator norms of matrix differences

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices with entries $0\leq A_{ij}, B_{ij}\leq 1,$ for all $i,j.$

Suppose we are given a bound on the operator norm as follows: $$\|A-B\|\leq \delta.$$

What is a good upper bound that we can infer on $\|A^\prime-B^\prime\|,$ where $A^\prime_{ij} = A_{ij}^2, B^\prime_{ij} = B_{ij}^2$? I want a bound of the form $f(n,\delta)$ which goes to zero as $\delta$ goes to zero.

Furthermore, if $A^\prime, B^\prime$ were obtained by raising the entries of $A,B$ respectively to power $p\geq 1,$ not necessarily integer, then what bound can we obtain on $\|A^\prime-B^\prime\|?$

Comment: I don't have a good answer, but the terms to look up, I think, are "Hadamard power" and "Hadamard product".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, there is an ugly but straight forward solution.

The operator norm is equivalent to the entry wise maximum norm $\| X \|_\max = \max_{1\le i,j \le n} |X_{i,j}|$. So there is some $C > 0$ (depending on $n$) such that
$$ C^{-1} \| X \|_\max \le \| X \| \le C \| X \|_\max. $$
Now, squaring is Lipschitz continuous on $[0,1]$ with the constant $2$. Thus, we have entry wise
$$ |A' - B'| \le 2 |A - B| $$
and
$$ \| A' - B' \| \le C \| A' - B' \|_\max \le 2 C \| A - B \|_\max \le 2 C^2 \| A - B \|. $$