# Deducing bounds on operator norms of matrix differences - part 2

Tags: matrices

A small variant on a question I asked previously: [Deducing bounds on operator norms of matrix differences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418867/deducing-bounds-on-operator-norms-of-matrix-differences)

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices with entries $0\leq A_{ij}, B_{ij}\leq 1,$ for all $i,j.$

Suppose we are given a bound on the operator norm of $A-B$ as follows: $$\|A-B\|\leq \delta.$$

What is a good upper bound that we can infer on $\|A^\prime-B^\prime\|,$ where $A^\prime_{ij} = \sqrt{A_{ij}}, B^\prime_{ij} = \sqrt{B_{ij}}$? I want a bound of the form $f(n,\delta)$ which goes to zero as $\delta$ goes to zero.

Since $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ is not Lipschitz, the answer to my previous question does not seem to be helpful here.

Comment: Hint: taking the square root on $[0,1]$ is Hölder continuous with exponent $\alpha=1/2$.

Comment: Thank you! That suffices. :)